# How to show the model summary in bambi?

Tags: python, bambi

I saw the [tutorial page of bambi](https://bambinos.github.io/bambi/notebooks/getting_started.html#getting-started) printing the model detail after you created a model (as this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QmJ2.png)). However, when I am using bambi (0.12.0) in Colab Notebook, after I created a model nothing was printed.

I tried to look into the source code to see whether I could change some variables to print the model summary but I found nothing. How can I print the model summary after I create a bambi model?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to know what you're doing without an example. But in general you can do `print(model)` as shown here

```py
import bambi as bmb
df = bmb.data.load_data("my_data")
model = bambi.Model("y ~ x", df)
print(model)
```

```
       Formula: y ~ x
        Family: gaussian
          Link: mu = identity
  Observations: 50
        Priors: 
    target = mu
        Common-level effects
            Intercept ~ Normal(mu: 0.1852, sigma: 2.5372)
            x ~ Normal(mu: 0.0, sigma: 2.231)
        
        Auxiliary parameters
            sigma ~ HalfStudentT(nu: 4.0, sigma: 1.013)
```